# Division by zero on Cellfit using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using a fpdf to generate my report on pdf file and I'm trying to fit the text in the cell using CellFit function but the error says that >Division by zero in line 49. Please help me. Thank you. This is my code:

```
//Cell with horizontal scaling if text is too wide
function CellFit($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', 
$fill=false, $link='', $scale=false, $force=true)
{
    //Get string width
    $str_width=$this->GetStringWidth($txt);

    //Calculate ratio to fit cell
    if($w==0)
        $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
        $ratio = ($w-$this->cMargin*2)/$str_width; //This is line 49


    $fit = ($ratio < 1 || ($ratio > 1 && $force));
    if ($fit)
    {
        if ($scale)
        {
            //Calculate horizontal scaling
            $horiz_scale=$ratio*100.0;
            //Set horizontal scaling
            $this->_out(sprintf('BT %.2F Tz ET',$horiz_scale));
        }
        else
        {
            //Calculate character spacing in points
            $char_space=($w-$this->cMargin*2-$str_width)/max($this->MBGetStringLength($txt)-1,1)*$this->k;
            //Set character spacing
            $this->_out(sprintf('BT %.2F Tc ET',$char_space));
        }
        //Override user alignment (since text will fill up cell)
        $align='';
    }

    //Pass on to Cell method
    $this->Cell($w,$h,$txt,$border,$ln,$align,$fill,$link);

    //Reset character spacing/horizontal scaling
    if ($fit)
        $this->_out('BT '.($scale ? '100 Tz' : '0 Tc').' ET');
}
```

Comment: Make sure your values are above 0. Division by zero isnt possible. Can you post the content from $str_width?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but judging by your indentation I suspect you want to do *two* things for `if($w==0)` -- in that case, you **must** put those two things between `{` and `}`. Without them, only the first command falls within the condition and the second is executed regardless.

Comment: I get that code from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script62.php

Comment: I see. That means my previous comment is irrelevant, as the second statement is not indented as far in that code as it is in yours.

Comment: That example script is 14 years old and doesn't take that many edge cases into account (like what happens when `$txt` is an empty string). When you get this error, what is the value of `$str_width`? If it is `0`, what is the value of `$txt`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan thank you so much for that explanation. Now, I understand what the error means. The value of  $str_width must not be null or zero.

Comment: Exactly. That function is intended to make text fit inside a cell. If you don't have any text to put in a cell (i.e. `$txt` is null or an empty string), don't use that function (or modify it to be able to handle that situation).

Comment: @rickdenhaan Hello, The error is produce because $txt is null or an empty string. How the code can be modify in order to work with NULL or empty string. Can you help, since there is no answer for many years?

Comment: @Yad Young Did you find a solution to the code, as i am having the same issue. I have null or empty string in some cells.

Comment: the problem is here and need a modification for NULL and empty string.    `//Get string width`
    `$str_width=$this->GetStringWidth($txt);`

    `//Calculate ratio to fit cell`
    `if($w==0)`
        `$w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;`
        `$ratio = ($w-$this->cMargin*2)/$str_width;`

Comment: @Sebastian Waldbauer can you fix php

Comment: @YvetteLee You could try something like `if (empty($txt)) return;` as the first thing in that function (before the `$str_width` definition).

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you, since i am not expert in php can you modify it as a solution.

Comment: I added before `if ($txt==NULL) {($txt='---');}`

Answer (score 0):

I added this and fix the problem for me. My values were NULL.

```
//Cell with horizontal scaling if text is too wide
function CellFit($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', 
$fill=false, $link='', $scale=false, $force=true)
{

//Add this line here, Convert NULL to '---'. 
if (empty($txt)) 
{
    $txt='---';
}

     //Get string width
     $str_width=$this->GetStringWidth($txt);
```

Comment: `if ($txt==NULL)` should be `if(is_null($txt))` for far better coding consistency

Comment: And `($txt='---');` should not have brackets: `$txt = '---';`

Comment: Also, for consistency you should probably be using `if (empty($txt)) ` . This would then also fit the default value for `$txt` given by the function.